Different perturbations?
In Newtonian gravity and gravitational waves the metric ($g_{\mu\nu}$) changes. The metric tells us how to measure distances in a spacetime (in this case the flat $\eta_{\mu\nu}$), and is correlated in both cases to the perturbation ($h_{\mu\nu}$) that modifies it, giving:
$$ g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu} $$
with $h_{\mu\nu} \ll 1$.
Therefore, by inserting the necessary simplifications into the field equation, for waves this is reduced to the expression:
$$ \Box \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = −16\pi GT_{\mu\nu} $$
where $\bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = h_{\mu\nu} − hη_{\mu\nu}/2$ is the trace-reversed metric perturbation, obtained by choosing the Lorenz gauge.
The amplitude of the wave depends on the nature of the source that is producing the gravitational radiation and the simplest method is to treat, when possible, the source with the quadruple approximation. In such a case the spatial components can be determined from:
$$ \bar{h}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{2G}{c^4r} I¨_{\mu\nu} $$
noting the similarity of this term with that of $-2GM/rc^2$ which instead characterizes the Newtonian limit.
So in both cases a very small variation of $g_{\mu\nu}$ is created starting from the flatness condition of $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, but what I don't understand is why a perturbation of a gravitational wave traveling in a flat spacetime can interact with another perturbation while that which is created by the Newtonian field in the same flat spacetime, no.

Here's a guide to using MathJaX on this site.  Please [edit] your question to include this notation;  it will make it much easier to read and you're more likely to get good answers that way.

Ohhh thanks you so much @John Rennie !

It is not clear to me what you are trying to ask in the last paragraph. It does not help that the last paragraph is effectively one sentence. Could you clarify?

I don't understand why, even if both are a perturbation of flat spacetime, gravitational waves undergo the superposition rule by interacting with each other like other waves, while for Newtonian fields the superposition principle requires the forces deriving from independent fields to be added independently.

For example, if we want to find the resultant force created by multiple masses M that a test mass m experiences, we should add them individually. There is no concept of a single perturbation being created as happens with waves. It is as if a point of spacetime ημν where the test mass is located simultaneously undergoes multiple perturbations independent of each other but this seems absurd to me, yet in all the texts the Newtonian fields are described as non-interacting.
